# how to change elements on UIpickerView pushing a button or pushing another button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller, uipickerviewdelegate

I have an application, that in the main view, have 3 buttons, and the 2 firts buttons have to show an `UIPickerView` for a selection of event (one of them) and a selection of time (the second).

`UIPickerViewDelegate` only let me to implement the methods one time, so, how can I do for change the content of the `UIPickerView`.

Here is mi .m code:

```
    #import "Home_ViewController.h"

    @interface Home_ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Home_ViewController

@synthesize index,arrayHoras,arrayRutas,pickerView, rutaId, horas, botonHoras, botonRuta, hora;

- (IBAction)selectRuta:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [pickerView setHidden:NO];
}


- (IBAction)horasBoton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [pickerView setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    hora = 1;
    arrayRutas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayHoras = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", nil];

    sqlite3 *turutaDB;
    NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *databasePath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turuta.db"];

    NSLog(@"path de la bbdd: %@",  databasePath);
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &turutaDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"2 Base de datos creada y abierta con exito");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Ha fallado la apertura de la bbdd");
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaRutas;
    NSString *querySQLrutas = @"SELECT id,nombre FROM rutas";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [querySQLrutas UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaRutas, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Consulta preparada ok");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
    }


    while (sqlite3_step(sentenciaRutas) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *selectRutas = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentenciaRutas, 1)];

        [arrayRutas addObject:selectRutas];


    }



    sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaRutas);

  //  [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(!botonHoras.isTouchInside) {
        return [arrayHoras count];
    } else  {
        return [arrayRutas count];
    }

}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(!botonHoras.isTouchInside) {
        return [arrayHoras objectAtIndex:row];
    } else  {
        return [arrayRutas objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (!botonHoras.isTouchInside) {
        horas= [[arrayHoras objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
        botonHoras.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Horas", horas];
        [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];

    } else {


        //GMSPolylineOptions *optionsLine = [GMSPolylineOptions options];
        GMSMutablePath *ruta = [GMSMutablePath path];


        sqlite3 *turutaDB;
        NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *databasePath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turuta.db"];

        NSLog(@"path de la bbdd: %@",  databasePath);
        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &turutaDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"2 Base de datos creada y abierta con exito");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Ha fallado la apertura de la bbdd");
        }

        sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaId;
        NSString *querySQLid = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT id FROM rutas WHERE nombre = '%@'", [arrayRutas objectAtIndex:row]];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [querySQLid UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaId, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Consulta preparada ok");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
        }


        while (sqlite3_step(sentenciaId) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentenciaId, 0)];

            rutaId = [id intValue];
            NSLog(@"%d",rutaId);


        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaId);

        sqlite3_stmt *sentenciaPolyLine;
        NSString *querySQLpoliline =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT coordx,coordy FROM config_ruta WHERE id_ruta = %d", rutaId];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(turutaDB, [querySQLpoliline UTF8String], -1, &sentenciaPolyLine, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Consulta preparada ok");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Consulta ha fallado al preparar: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(turutaDB));
        }


        while (sqlite3_step(sentenciaPolyLine) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *x = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                           (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentenciaPolyLine, 1)];

            NSString *y = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                           (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentenciaPolyLine, 0)];

            double coordx = [x doubleValue];
            double coordy = [y doubleValue];
            NSLog(@"%f | %f",coordy,coordx);


            [ruta addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordy, coordx)];

        }



    sqlite3_finalize(sentenciaPolyLine);


        botonRuta.titleLabel.text = [arrayRutas objectAtIndex:row];

        [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
        [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }

}




- (IBAction)rutaboton:(id)sender {

}
```

Some help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag indicating which button was pressed. Then you check that flag in each of the picker view data source and delegate methods.

Add an `int` property to your class. In the `selectRuta:` method set the property to `1`. In the `horasBoton:` method, set the property to `2`.

Then you picker view method look something like this (this assumes your property was named `buttonType`):

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(self.buttonType == 1) {
        return [arrayRutas count];
    } else  {
        return [arrayHoras count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but now I have another problem, if I push first button, when I select one row, and push the other button, the pickerView show me the data from first button.

And If I push second button first, show me the data form second button, select one row, and push the other button, the pickerView show me the data from the button I pressed first time.

How I do for remove all the data when I select a row and hide the pickerView?

Comment: You should reload the picker view in your two button methods (after setting the `buttonType` property).

Comment: Just adding `[self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];` after setting the buttonType property